# Sequelize, include the data of a relation in the response of a creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I manage to retrieve the data of an element and its relation like this with findAll, it's work:

```
// Comments
include: [
{
    model: User,
}
```

But I would also like to recover this relation in the response after a creation :

```
Comments.create(
    {
         ...comment.dataValues,
    }
).then((response) => {
    // Here response return the information of the comment but not the information of its 
       relationship with the user
}
```

I tried with this but it doesn't work :

```
  include: [{
    association: Comments.User,
    include: [ User.name]
  }]
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: In then block you can get the Comment like this `Comments.findByPk(response.id), {include: [User]})`

Comment: Thank you it works! :)
On the other hand it makes a second query for the server, I think it is also possible to recover the data in one go.

Comment: When I face this problem I solve it like this, I don't know if it is possible to recover the data from the response.